# Hover over button with animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to create button, with animation inside. Button contain text and animation. Right now my animation(png switchs to gif) is working when I hover my mouse over it, but not working when I hover the rest of the button. I need help with creating right event listeners.
One - mouse over button - image change to gif and back.(when mouse removed)
Two - mouse over image - image changed to gif and back(when mouse removed).

I understand how it's supposed to work, but lost with code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://animate.style/

and try this one as an example:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button id="myButton">Hover over me</button>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
  const button = document.getElementById('myButton');

  button.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    button.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__bounce');
  });

  button.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    button.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__bounce');
  });
</script>
```

Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8erqfv7y/2/